# How to get back your local files after check in?

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2015

I have just done a check in for backup and someone posted his changes to TFS. And now even though I was uploading some of my files got merged with his code.

Is there any way to get back the files I had locally on my PC or do I have to rewrite the code?

Comment: who checked-in first?  you or your colleague?

Comment: @rerwinRR he checked in last month and now I wanted to do a backup and ended up with the old code on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to recover the previous version of the folder because Windows saved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the History of the project, and get the previous version. TFS keeps all versions of your project, you can easily get any version of your project.

Comment: but my version was not published on the server